# Does calling DateTime.AddDays with a whole number always leave the time unchanged?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time

Consider the following code which attempts to get a `DateTime` that's equivalent to the local time "midnight yesterday":

```
DateTime midnightYesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1.0d);
```

Will this *always* result in a `DateTime` with a time component of 00:00:00 -- regardless of any corner cases such as leap days, leap seconds, or what the local time zone is?

More generally: Does calling `DateTime.AddDays`, passing a whole number as a parameter, always result in a `DateTime` being returned that has the exact same time component as the original `Datetime`?

The [MSDN documentation for DateTime.AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not address this specific question.

Comment: You can look at the source http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,f5cb6edd98581ca2

Comment: @Steve And based on that, it looks like the answer is, "No", since it's just using a constant number of milliseconds, without regard for events like daylight savings or leap seconds.

Comment: I just wrote up a quick test that creates a DateTime for 2017-01-01 and calls AddDays(-1d) on it. Given that 2016-12-31 had a leap second, I'd expect the result to be off from 00:00:00 by one second, but the result is (unexpectedly) exactly 2016-12-31 00:00:00? Any insight?

Comment: Additional [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx#datetime_ops) says "Operations by members of the DateTime type take into account details such as leap years and the number of days in a month."  and "Conversion operations between time zones (such as between UTC and local time, or between one time zone and another) take daylight saving time into account, but arithmetic and comparison operations do not."

Comment: Hmm... I get the same result checking daylight savings. Trolling through the source, I'm not sure how this is accomplished. I see it's ultimately converting a full day's worth of milliseconds into Ticks, making that adjustment, and then doing a new DateTime() based on the new Tick value, but even the DateTime constructor doesn't seem to account for this.

Comment: FYI, you dont need to specify "d" or any decimal. In your case, simply, write DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn why the answer is No based on that? Seems to me the answer (based on that) should be yes.

Comment: Here's someone else's experiences that you may find insightful. [DateTime arithmetic and Daylight Saving Time](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/03/27/datetime-arithmetic-and-daylight-saving-time/)

Comment: @Evk On November 5th, from midnight Sunday morning to midnight Monday morning is only 23 hours. We fall back and lose an hour. Adding a simple 24 hours worth of ticks would NOT preserve the time, but should instead show 1am Monday morning.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn well Hour, Minute, Second etc properties also do no perform any conversions, just use that ticks value. Hour for example does `ticks / 36000000000L % 24L`, so adding day worth of ticks cannot change it.

Comment: @Evk It can if a day isn't exactly 24 hours, as happens most places two or three times per year.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn but you just said above that "it's just using a constant number of milliseconds, without regard for events like daylight savings or leap seconds", so day is always 24 hour when doing DateTime.AddDays.

Comment: @Evk the Hours, Minutes, etc properties are not stored. Only ticks are stored, and other properties computed based on that. Adding 24 hours worth of milliseconds to a 23 hour day should change that.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: No, because a `DateTime` value doesn't represent an instant in time when the `Kind` is `Local` or `Unspecified`. If you use `.AddHours(24)` that performs arithmetic with no regard to time zone - it doesn't necessarily give you "the value what would occur in reality after 24 hours have elapsed". Basically `DateTime` tries to represent too many things in a single type - it's this sort of thing that made me write Noda Time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: To put it another way: the properties (year, month, day, hour etc) only take the underlying ticks into account, *not* the kind - and therefore they perform no time-zone-sensitive computations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `DateTime` does not account for leap seconds. You can read this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toffer/2005/01/31/datetime-not-as-simple-as-you-think/) from which you will see that because of this it doesn't really support UTC. Documentation states that:

> Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a
>   particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January
>   1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding ticks
>   that would be added by leap seconds)

2. About daylight saving time documentation states the following:

> Conversion operations between time zones (such as between UTC and
>   local time, or between one time zone and another) take daylight saving
>   time into account, *but arithmetic and comparison operations do not.*

That means that adding days (which is arithmetic operation) to `DateTime` instance, even if it has kind `Local` (so represents time in local timezone) does not take DST into account. That makes performing any arithmetic operations on datetimes with kind `Local` a really bad idea. If you need to do that with date times - first convert it to UTC (that has no notion of DST), perform operation then convert back to local (conversion as stated above *does* take DST into account).

You can also look at source code to see that datetime value is stored as a number internally (number of ticks) and adding days just adds fixed value to that number. Calculating hour\minute\second use that value and perform fixed operations (just a division) to obtain target value. None of those operations account for anything like leap seconds, time zones or anything else. So the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Huh? If you have a DateTime that is a second Sunday in March, and you .AddDays(1), and that just adds a fixed number of ticks to an internally stored ticks value, doesn't that mean the local time would change, and the answer to his question would be "no"?

Comment: @John but why local time would change? As explained in answer, all arithmetic operations on DateTime does not take anything at all into account. So adding 1 day is just that - adding one day. Adding one day to any Sunday 00:00, in any timezone, will turn that into Monday 00:00. For that reason if you ever add\substract anything from Local DateTime in C# - you are doing something wrong, because DateTime in C# is poorly designed.