# DateTime.Parse with overflow

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there an alternative to DateTime.Parse that will accept an overflowing date or month like this?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class DateTimeTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestOverflowOfDay()
        {
            var dt = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-32");

            var str = dt.ToString();

            Assert.AreEqual("2020-02-01 00:00:00", str);
        }
    }
}
```

This code results in a `System.FormatException` on the `DateTime.Parse` line.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Can I parse the string allowing overflow so it will be treated as `"2020-02-01"`?

<strike>That seems to be standard in other languages/implementations.</strike>

Comment: ”That seems to be standard in other languages/implementations.” What? Can you name a language/implementation that supports this?

Comment: Even javascript won't allow that: `Date.parse("2020-01-32")` => NaN

Comment: So you want `DateTime.Parse("2020-01").AddDays(int.Parse("32") - 1);`

Comment: Hm, maybe I got that wrong. I thought other languages were tolerant with overflows, but clearly not.

Comment: Just found that Java's `SimpleDateFormat` allows a day of 32, although you can disallow it by `setLenient(false)`... That said, `SimpleDateFormat` is an *awful* API and far from standard.

Comment: As long as you know what you do, its not that awful. I have to implement that awfulness myself instead.

Comment: AddDays is probably having the drawback of altering time if we pass a daylight saving time boundary.

Comment: @AndersLindén: No, I don't believe AddDays does that at all. You've speculated that it will in another comment - why not *try* it rather than speculating?

Comment: _"As long as you know what you do, its not that awful"_ - yes, inventing your own DateTime format _is_ awful, no matter what. Why do you need this? Can you consider alternatives?

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried it, but I am afraid my testing is not conclusive.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am traversing weeks, using mondays 00:00. I need to be able to go from one monday to the next, but I cannot be sure `.AddDays(7)` will do that.

Comment: AddDays will be fine for that. Heck, you could use my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) project and use `LocalDate` instead, as that couldn't *possible* change the the time of day (it doesn't have one, or a time zone). But I agree with CodeCaster that avoiding this date format in the first place would be better if at all possible. (Do you have to cope with negative days? What about zero? Or invalid months? Years?)

Comment: If I use AddDays, I will start from a date that I know is valid and it will always give me a valid date, I do not need to traverse backwards.

Comment: None of that explains why you need to represent an invalid date as a string to start with though.

Comment: True, but I instead stumbled upon `var nextmonday = new DateTime(year, monday.Month, monday.Day + 7);` which is only to forget.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "which is only to forget" - but that will throw an exception if `monday.Day + 7` is out of range for the month.  I've still seen *no* indication of why you believe you need to parse an invalid date string.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would like to be able to use both `DateTime.Parse` and `new DateTime()` with overflowing input, but now I will use `.AddDays`, which seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you could do this without rolling your own. If you know the format of your datetimes, you can do the following, or something similar.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var date = GetCustomDateTime("2020-01-32");

            Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        }

        private static DateTime GetCustomDateTime(string dateTimeString)
        {
            var split = dateTimeString.Split('-');
            var yearMonth = DateTime.ParseExact($"{split[0]}-{split[1]}", "yyyy-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return yearMonth.AddDays(int.Parse(split[2])-1);
        }
```

This is not affected by daylight savings time, sourced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/performing-arithmetic-operations?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> Arithmetic or comparison operations on local date and time values do
> not consider whether a particular value is ambiguous or invalid, nor
> do they take account of the effect of any adjustment rules that result
> from the local time zone's transition to or from daylight saving time.

Comment: And that will not alter the time because of daylight saving time?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855886/does-calling-datetime-adddays-with-a-whole-number-always-leave-the-time-unchange), I'm of the belief that DateTime does not take day light savings time into account.

Comment: I saw that as well, but I am not sure that is conclusive, when the accepted answer discusses leap seconds for some reason.

Comment: https://rextester.com/ZKC79199

I ran it 366 times, this should test it fully, yeah?

Comment: But you only have one server environment/locale setting doing that 366 tests, so I am not convinced.

Comment: [AddDays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netcore-3.1), "The AddDays method takes into account leap years and the number of days in a month when performing date arithmetic." I feel like if it was affected by DST it would be noted in their documentation.

Comment: Also just found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/performing-arithmetic-operations?redirectedfrom=MSDN). "Arithmetic or comparison operations on local date and time values do not consider whether a particular value is ambiguous or invalid, nor do they take account of the effect of any adjustment rules that result from the local time zone's transition to or from daylight saving time."

Comment: Please, add that reference to your answer if you want @Garrison Becker.